# No module named

Tags: python, google-app-engine, import, package

I'm writing in python for google app engine. When i compile my project it gets not error. When I use it on the server I get error on the `import`.

For example I am importing a method from another class like this:

```
from src.receiver.receive_smth import add_to_smth_db
```

The error I get looks like this:

```
<type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: No module named src.receiver.receive_smth
```

The weird thing is that when I automatically import this dependency I get something like:

```
from receiver.receive_smth import add_to_smth_db
```

(notice that the `src` is missing in front of the receiver), however my project is marked with errors.

Google appengine imports and django work fine besides a warning that

> You are using the default Django version (0.96). The default Django version will change in an App Engine release in the near future.

**[Update]**

One thing I noticed is that my packages do not contain `__init__.py` scripts (I am working on windows).  Any ideas on how to configure packages properly?

Warning regarding Django version fixed

```
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'
from google.appengine.dist import use_library
use_library('django', '1.1')
```

Comment: A directory that doesn't contain `__init__.py` isn't a package at all. What exactly do you mean by "when you compile your project" it doesn't get errors? You don't generally compile python (although modules are compiled to .pyc for you when they're first imported, there are no "compiler errors" per se.)

Comment: well, the project runs without any exceptions or errors until this point. Also, I dont get red marked errors as usual. I copied an __init__.py from another project of mine and it worked. But what is the proper way of setting a folder as a package in python?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you IDE can add your project to python sys path on your system. Or framework can do that then you setup your project.
Try to use realitive import http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/